# rails, ruby, paperclip check if file exists condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, paperclip, each

I have a Post and Comment Model (post has_many comments, comment belongs_to post)

I'm trying to display a random comment but only if a picture exists with the comment (using paperclip). Here is my code:

```
<% count = 0 %>
<% @shuffle_posts = @posts.shuffle %>
<% @shuffle_posts.each do |post| %>
    <% if post.comments.sample.picture.file? %>
      <%= link_to image_tag(post.comments.sample.picture.url(:thumb)),post_path(post) %>
      <% count += 1 %>
    <% else %>
      <% @shuffle_posts = @posts.shuffle %>
    <% end %>
  <% break if count ==1 %>
<% end %>
```

This code runs, but when I refresh a few times, I will get comments without a picture! I'm thinking it has something to do with my ".file?" condition, but not sure what is causing it to display because I think my code should be catching the comments with no pictures.

If someone is seeing something different / or could offer another solution, that would be super helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view is not supposed to get all that business logic inside.

To me, it doesn't make sense to call shuffle on a collection, and then loop until you find a post that matches the condition. The code you wrote it's unnecessary complicated.

My suggestion is to filter the recordset at query level. Fetch only records where the image field is not empty, then get a random record from that set.

Assuming the image field is called `picture_path`. In the controller

```
@random_comment = Comment.where("picture_path IS NOT NULL").shuffle
```

and the view will simply be

```
<%= link_to image_tag(@random_comment.picture.url(:thumb)), post_path(@random_comment.post) %>
```

Note: It's not clear from your question, if you want to display a random comment or post. You said comment, but the code fetched a random post.

Note2: Note the difference between my view and your view. My view is a single line, with no business logic and only presentation logic. That's what it should be. No variable assignation or business logic.

Comment: Thanks, Simone! Agreed on all fronts that the biz logic needs to be in the controller. I was going down a bad road. I can't seem to get your .where condition to work. .where("picture IS NOT NULL") throw an error: undefined column. The column name (using paperclip) for the picture is 'picture'. Can you advise?

Comment: It's likely the field is not `picture`. Inspect the file `schema.rb` to get the proper attribute name.